# route table explanation

Tags: networking, routing

I'm a newbie. Recently I used the command `ip route ls` to print my route table. Here is the content:

```
111.211.3.192/26 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 111.211.3.205 metric 2
```

I'm curious about the meaning of `proto kernel` and `scope link`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm partially quoting the man page.

**scope** *type* is the  scope  of  the  destinations  covered  by the route prefix. `scope link` means that within the network segment of the device communication is allowed through this link. Towards other network segments routing should be used.

**protocol** *type* is the routing protocol identifier of this route. `proto kernel` means:

> The route was installed by the kernel during autoconfiguration.

For more information, see:

- The man page that can be read by typing `man ip` in a terminal window.
- Several [topics](https://serverfault.com/search?q=scope%20link) on Serverfault. Especially [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/63014/ip-address-scope-parameter) on scope.

Comment: What does `src` mean?

Answer (score 2):

for `proto kernel`, it is a route added automatically when you assign an address to an interface which is not /32.
Lets say in your case, you assigned an address `111.211.3.193/26` to `wlan0` (or some other in same subnet), kernel automatically adds route to whole subnet via this interface during auto-configuration. The only way to avoid this is assigning a /32 address to the interface.

Comment: IT'S NOT TRUE You can stop the kernel from adding this route by passing noprefixroute to the call to ip addr add